# Unable to access a string from SharedPreferences in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication, sharedpreferences

So I have two screens, a set password screen and an enter password (login) screen. I'd like it to pop up the enter password screen if there is no password (ie, the application's never been used) and upon subsequent launches go to the login screen. If the user enters a password, it compares with the value stored in sharepreferences and continues to the menu if it's correct. But the login screen seems unable to access the password after the set-password screen is used.

How do I make the login screen see the password set by the registration page?

Here's the create password code:

```
public class CreatePassword extends Activity {
public EditText setPass1, setPass2;
String newPass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_createpassword);

    setPass1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSetPassword);
    setPass2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextRepeatSetPassword);
}

public void btnSubmitNewPassword(View v){
    if(setPass1.getText().toString() != "") {
        if (setPass1.getText().toString().equals(setPass2.getText().toString())) {
            newPass = setPass1.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
            prefEditor.putString("password", newPass);
            prefEditor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newPass, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Password Set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(CreatePassword.this, Menu.class));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Desired Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}//end CreatePassword class
```

And the EnterPassword (login) screen that refuses to use the password just set:

```
public class EnterPassword extends Activity {

EditText editTextPasswordAttempt;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
String passwordAttempt, passwordActual;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enterpassword);

    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean passwordExists = sharedPref.contains("password");

    if(passwordExists == false){
        startActivity(new Intent(EnterPassword.this, CreatePassword.class));
    }

    editTextPasswordAttempt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
}

public void btnSubmitToMenu(View v){

    passwordActual = sharedPref.getString("password", );
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), passwordActual, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    passwordAttempt = editTextPasswordAttempt.getText().toString();

    if(passwordAttempt.equals(passwordActual)) {
        startActivity(new Intent(EnterPassword.this, Menu.class));
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 2 different SharedPreferences.

In `CreatePassword` activity you do:

```
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

But in `EnterPassword` activity you do:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

If you use the same line in both Activities it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use same **name** of SharedPreferences while access SharedPreferences values.Access SharedPreferences in **EnterPassword** activity with same way using below line:

```
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
```